# $($(elContainer).find('.image-wrapper').eq(index)[0]).find(' > img').remove();

Tags: javascript

I want convert this jquery code:

```
$($(elContainer).find('.image-wrapper').eq(index)[0]).find(' > img').remove();
$(elContainer).find('.image-wrapper').eq(index)[0].appendChild(img);
```

to Javascript. Pls help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('elContainerSelector .image-wrapper > img').remove()
const node = document.createElement("img")
document.querySelector('elContainerSelector .image-wrapper').appendChild(node)
```

Comment: Tks bro, i'll trying